# Do I have to use malloc every time I return a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I'm working on a program that has few undiscovered memory leaks. The code is literally decades old and written by an unknown person. I have functions that return `char *` and I was wondering if I need to `free` the memory.
Specifically I have a function that replaces a substring in a string, I return the pointer to the newly `malloc`ed memory. Do I `free` the original string ?

Original version:

```
return(findAndReplace(str, "&#149;",rstring));
```

New version:

```
char *result = findAndReplace(str, "&#149;", rstring);
free(str);
return result;
```

Questions being: Can I be 100% sure that since I had a pointer returned from somewhere else that memory has been allocated? Is it safe to free that memory (assuming it's not used anywhere else)?

Edit:
str comes from here:

```
str = axiom_element_get_text(element, env, messageDataNode);
```

Comment: The answer depends on how `findAndReplace` is implemented and on whether `str` was allocated with `malloc`. Pointers have many uses; being handles to allocated memory is just one of them.

Comment: You can only `free` memory that was returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`. Check whether `str` fits this condition.

Comment: @xyious-- if memory is being allocated in precompiled library functions, you should probably be using matching deallocation functions from the library anyway....

Comment: I would really like to know what the donvotes are about, though.... Feel like this is a question that would help a lot of people....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You need clearly-defined contracts for your functions' pre and post conditions. In your "old version", the contract seems to be that the caller provides a pointer `str` to an arbitrary string; storage and lifetime of this string are up to the caller. In the "new version", you've changed it so that the caller must provide a pointer to a string obtained by `malloc`, and so that the pointer is no longer valid (the object has been freed) after your function returns.

Your core problem is most likely *lack of any documentation of the contracts in the existing codebase*, meaning you have to reverse-engineer the original author's intents. But you shouldn't go trying to change any of thus until you've documented the current situation, decided if a change makes sense, and ensured that you can safely change every point in the existing code that was assuming the original undocumented contracts.

Comment: I was just asking because I want to learn, I just had a specific example to go off of. How can I return a pointer from a function without allocating memory for where the pointer points to ?

Comment: A pointer can point to any object whose lifetime has not ended. A very common case is returning a pointer to *a part of* a larger object. The canonical example is something like `strchr` or `strstr`, but if you think bigger, a function that searches a tree or other data structure for a particular node and returns a pointer to that node is an example too. Of course you do have many situations where the purpose of a function is to "make something new" and in that case you allocate storage for the pointer you will return to point to.

Comment: In your example where the function is named `findAndReplace`, it's up to you to determine if you (and if you can) treat it as "making something new" (the derived string with the replacement performed) or "changing something that already exists". In the latter case you can only really do that "in-place" if the source string is large enough to hold the replacement.

Comment: @xyious-- "How can I return a pointer from a function without allocating memory for where the pointer points to ?" It could be as simple as returning a pointer to a string literal.

Comment: So since I assume there's no way to find out whether or not we're allowed to free the memory and since I have no access to the source code of the function that returns a pointer (it's part of the library I just have the definition). Do I just have to live with a potential memory leak and leave it at that ?

Comment: @xyious: For a non-long-lived program with an upper bound on the number of calls during its lifetime, that may be a viable solution. Otherwise you probably need to reverse-engineer the function whose contract you don't understand. You can use breakpoints to determine if it calls malloc, or disassemble it, etc...

Comment: Yeah the problem is that it's a daemon. The process runs 24 hours a day and the function gets called thousands of times (I know that's not really a lot, but I have many functions to go through to check for memory leaks).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe the `free` memory that was not allocated by `malloc` in the first place. You can use pointers without malloc/free but in a non-trivial program you are likely to be using malloc and free at certain, but not all, places.

If you are trying to detect memory leaks in your program, a tool like [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) might help.